# c++ Cycle cuts out randomly?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, for-loop, cycle

First I have this class:

```
class Recept
{
    private:
       int serves;
       string* ingredient_name;
       int* ingredient_number;
       float difficulty;

    public:
       Recept(int a=0, string* b = NULL, float c = 0.0, int* d = NULL)
       {
          serves = a;
          ingredient_name = b;
          difficulty = c;
          ingredient_number = d;

       }

    ~Recept()
    {
        delete ingredient_name;
        delete ingredient_number;
    }
};
```

An object to store all the available recipes:

```
Recept* AvailableRecipes;
```

And this function to initialize this object. The only thing main() does is call this function.

```
void OpenRecipes()
{

    SetCurrentDirectory("\Recipes");
    system("dir /b > a.txt");

    ifstream filelist;
    filelist.open("a.txt");
    stringstream newstrstr;
    newstrstr << filelist.rdbuf();
    string seged = newstrstr.str();

    filelist.clear();
    filelist.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    newstrstr.str(std::string());
    AvailableRecipes = new Recept[count_words(seged)-1];

    string filename;
    int counter = 0;

    cout << "Total number of iterations needed: " << count_words(seged) << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < count_words(seged) ; i++)
    {
        cout << "i: " << i << endl;
        filelist >> filename;

        if(filename != "a.txt")
        {
            stringstream newstrstr;
            ifstream input;

            input.open(filename.c_str());
            newstrstr << input.rdbuf();


            string seged2 = newstrstr.str();
            int ingredient_num[(count_words(seged2) - 2) / 2];
            string ingredient_name[(count_words(seged2) - 2) / 2];
            float difficulty;
            int serving;
            input.clear();
            input.seekg(0, ios::beg);

            input >> serving >> difficulty;

            int IntContain;
            string StringContain;

            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(ingredient_num)/sizeof(ingredient_num[0]); j++)
            {
                input >> IntContain >> StringContain;
                ingredient_num[j] = IntContain;
                ingredient_name[j] = StringContain;


           }

            Recept a = Recept(serving, ingredient_name, difficulty, ingredient_num);

            AvailableRecipes[counter] = a;

           counter++;


            newstrstr.str(std::string());

            input.close();

            cout << "No error so far" << endl;


        }

    }

}
```

Basically this function is supposed to:
-Read filenames from subfolder /Recipes

-Store filenames in "a.txt" in this same folder.

-Open the files 1 by 1, and create a Recipe object based from the text in them.

-Add Recipe object to AvailableRecipes object array.

The problem is, the cycle cuts out seemingly randomly, for some reason. I'd like to know why, and how I could fix it :s

Example output:

```
Total number of iterations needed: 4
i: 0
No error so far
i: 1
i: 2

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.312 s
Press any key to continue.
```

//In this example, iteration 0 was working with a valid file ( !="a.txt)
,iteration 1 was dealing with "a.txt, and iteration 2 was another valid file.

I'm a rookie, very much so, so please be nice :/
Using CodeBlocks, with minGW on win64

Comment: Side notes: you do not obey the rule of five. You should not use raw pointers but unique_ptr or stl containers (here: vector) where possible.

Comment: The return code of your program says it: an exception (bad access) occured. Run it under a debugger to check where the exception occurs.

Comment: Compile the program as debug version. It will tell you in which line the problem occurred. 0xC0000005 means "access violation". So at some point your program reads from some memory that it shouldn't. Such things happen, when using raw pointers like AvailableRecipes[counter](what Werner said).

Comment: Also there is a problem with `ingredient_name`: it is a pointer to string, and the class `Recept` just copies the pointer in the constructor (instead of copying of the string) and deletes this string in the desctructor.

Comment: You're multiple-deleting memory. You need to either follow "the rule of three (or five)" or start using the collections in the standard library.

Comment: I've narrowed the error down to this line:

input >> serving >> difficulty;
       
But I just cant see whats wrong with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems already in these two lines

```
        Recept a = Recept(serving, ingredient_name, difficulty, ingredient_num);

        AvailableRecipes[counter] = a;
```

First you create `a` which stores pointers to the local variables `ingredient_name` and `ingredient_num`. These pointers will be dangling as soon as you leave the if-statement where they are declared.

Then on the next line, you create a copy of `a` in the `AvailableRecipes` array. Now you have two copies of each pointer.

Eventually, all of this will end up in the destructor of `Recept`, trying to delete the pointers. Not only are they dangling, but you also have several copies of each. Double fault!

Comment: Thank you! This solved everything :)

I rewrote my constructor to create arrays on the heap, and instead of copying a pointer, I copy the full contents of the local variable to it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't random at all. From what understand based on the code you posted:
1) there are 4 words that you need to store in the array.

2) you create an array of size [word_count] - 1 = 3 (i.e. with indexes i range [0..2]).

3) Your for loop has 4 iterations (same as [word_count]) (i.e. goes through indexes within range [0..3]).

4) When you attempt to access the array element with index `3`, you get access violation error, since it doesn't exist (remember: your array has a maximum index of `2`). And that is what the exception code `0xC0000005` means - access violation.

Comment: There are Three words that need to be stored in the array:

Three text files. But!
a.txt is also in this folder, and "a.txt" contains FOUR lines: The names of the three valid files, and its own name (a.txt), which will be thrown away. Thats why I create (word_count -1) size array, since one of the words in the file is junk.

Comment: @aurellb I explained entire workflow in my answer. If there are `count_words(seged) - 1` elements that you care about, why are you looping through `count_words(seged)` elements? I just took a closer look at your code, and what I said still holds. Yes, you skip the 1st elementa but, because of that, you try putting your actual values in array at indexes 1, 2, 3 (since you skipped 0), while the array only holds 3 places where the values can go, indexed with 0, 1, 2. Notice, that it doesn't have index `3`?